# Testing Session timeout in Visual Studio 2013 Express

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, visual-studio-2013, session-timeout

I am using VS 2013 Express for Web. I used to create a simple login exercise. When the user logs in, I create this form authentication in my login action method:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Name, false);
```

and immediately place the name into a session:

```
Session["name"] = model.name;
```

My session settings in the Web.config is as follows:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="10"/> 
</authentication>
<sessionState timeout="1" /> <!-- only one minute-->
```

After the assignment of the session variable, if I pause execution at a break point, shouldn't the Session time out after 1 minute and becomes empty? Currently, it continues having a value.

Comment: How are you checking the value if paused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value won't actually change whilst you're on a break-point, but you could set a break on the `Session_End` in the global.asax file to detect when the session times-out. Take a look at [working with Global.asax](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/working-with-the-aspnet-globalasax-file/) file to understand the different events.